# Why it dont compile, but compile on cpp.sh

Tags: c++, qt

i have that QT:

**Qt Creator 4.1.0
Based on Qt 5.7.0 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit)**

Built on Aug 24 2016 14:56:50

And next code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
[enter image description here][1]
// универсальный полиморфизм (шаблон)
template <typename T>
class value {
public:
    T val;
};

// динамический полиморфизм

class var {
public:
    virtual char type(){return 'U';}
};

class Int:public var {
public:
    char type(){return 'I';}
};

class String:public var {
public:
    char type(){return 'S';}
};

class Float:public var {
public:
    char type(){return 'F';}
};

class M:public var{};


std::string gettype(var* opt){
    if (opt->type() == 'U'){
        return "unknown";
    } else if (opt->type() == 'I') {
        return "int";
    } else if (opt->type() == 'S'){
        return "string";
    } else if (opt->type() == 'F'){
        return "float";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    // универсальный полиморфизм
    value<int> n;
    n.val = 5;

    value<string> s;
    s.val = "text";

    cout << n.val << endl;
    cout << s.val << endl;

    // динамический полиморфизм
    var* a = new Int();
    var* b = new String();
    var* c = new Float();
    var* x = new M();

    cout << gettype(a) << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

**It runs good on cpp.sh, but in my QT on win 8.1 don't work.**

"Binary" << ": the operator can not be found, taking the right operand type" std :: string "(or no acceptable conversion)"

Comment: `#include <string>`

Comment: And `[enter image description here][1]` is not valid C++ code.

Comment: Thank you for header that i need!

Comment: About image - dont know what is it, maybe bug, i delete them all while posting message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to include string.h using:

```
#include <string>
```

Then I would remove the line `[enter image description here][1]` , I don't know what it does and it's not C++ code.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes. All is okey. Thank You!